# Infragistics XamDataGrid - track selected row in view model

Tags: binding, viewmodel, infragistics

We're using Infragistics WPF v9.2 and MVVM

I'd like to track the currently selected row from the XamDataGrid as a property in the view model but I'm struggling to see how this is done. It looks like ActiveDataItem property would be the way to go but it doesn't appear to be on the WPF v9.2 grid.

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveDataItem property would allow you to bind what is the active record to a property in your VeiwModel but wouldn't give you the actual selection of the XamDataGrid.  For this you would need to use a custom behavior.  The following link has examples of this for some of the Infragistics Silverlight controls and you could use a similar approach with the XamDataGrid in WPF:

http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/devin_rader/archive/2011/06/01/using-behaviors-to-synchronize-selected-items-of-infragistics-silverlight-controls-to-a-viewmodel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you can, pls upgrade to 10.3.

had the same pain of trying to get WPF UltraGrid to work with MVVM with older 9 version.

v10.3 version is much easier and better integrated with MVVM.

not sure if upgrade costs money, we had sitewide license